# Python Telegram Bot запись определенных сообщений в Google Sheet

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet

Нужно записывать в таблицу Google Sheet определенные сообщения, отправляемые Телеграм ботом в ответ пользователю. Условно каждое выбранное сообщение - в новую ячейку. Так же в соседней колонке хотелось бы выводить дату отправки сообщения.

Пример:
->Бот, какой курс доллара сейчас?
-> 32 рубля 14 копеек

Записать "32 рубля 14 копеек" в таблицу Google Sheet

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо будет использовать апи гугла + настроить доступ к таблице

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime

# Настройка доступа к таблице
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
 #данные лог пас лучше не хардкодить
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('пусть до данных учетки', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('Название таблицы').sheet1

# Получение сообщения от пользователя
message_text = '32 рубля 14 копеек'
date_sent = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

# Запись сообщения в таблицу
row = [message_text, date_sent]
sheet.append_row(row)
```